# Use PHP to display new list item every 14 days

Tags: php, datetime, foreach

I am working with the following code to display a new list item every 14 days. The start date is **2020-02-01** and the end date is **2020-12-31**. No list items will be displayed on the start date. On **2020-02-15**, the first list item will be displayed. On **2020-02-29**, the second list item will be displayed. This will continue every 14 days until the end date is reached.

The list items are coming from a WordPress loop, so I am not sure if this code could be incorporated into the WP Query using date_query or should be kept separate and run after the query.

```
<?php
// Set the default timezone.
date_default_timezone_set('America/Edmonton');

$startDate = new DateTime('2020-02-01 00:00:00');
$endDate = new DateTime('2020-12-31 00:00:00');
$dateRange = new DatePeriod($startDate, new DateInterval('P14D'), $endDate);
$b = new DateTime('-14 days');
?>

<ul>
<?php foreach($dateRange as $date): ?>
    <?php $diff = $date->diff($b); ?>
    <?php if($diff->days <= 14): ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); ?>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

**Current Output**

- 2019-12-29
- 2020-01-12

The output is not as expected and I am needing some assistance in fixing my code as I am a PHP novice.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
// We start at your given start date
$startDate = new DateTime("2020-02-01");
// We define a date when to stop additional list items
$endDate = new DateTime("2020-12-31");
// We define the current time
$now = new DateTime();

// Modify date on the fly, by given time frame (readability)
// Ensures to display dates only between start+14day && end
while ($startDate->modify("+14 days") < $now && $startDate < $endDate) {
    echo '<li>' . $startDate->format("Y-m-d") . '</li>';
}
```

Comment: What have you changed, and why?

Comment: @Mruf Your code contains the following errors: `$dateTime` and `$endTime` are not defined. I assumed `$endTime` should be `$endDate`, but what about `$dateTime`.

Comment: Fixed it. Sorry

Comment: https://3v4l.org/1KurX you can fiddle around here. Just change $now so you can see what happens on certain days

Comment: @Mruf Thanks. Your code is working as expected now. Do you have any suggestions for integrating this with a WordPress query loop?

Comment: What exactly do you want to query? Do you want to group your posts in 2 week intervals?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this and it works:

```
<?php
// Set the default timezone.
date_default_timezone_set('America/Edmonton');

$startDate = new DateTime('2020-02-01 00:00:00');
$startDate->modify('+14 days');
$endDate = new DateTime('2020-12-31 00:00:00');
$dateRange = new DatePeriod($startDate, new DateInterval('P14D'), $endDate);
?>
<ul>
<?php foreach($dateRange as $date) { ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); ?>
        </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

I've added `$endDate->modify('+14 days');` which alters the timestamp (adds 2 weeks to the timestamp). And because `$dateRange` returns a timestamp for exactly every 2 weeks, I removed the if statement. You can learn more about `date->modify()` [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php).

Comment: What have you changed, and why?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I've edited my answer. Should I go more in depth about the changes I made?

Comment: @LeonKunštek I have tested your code locally, but it prints all of the dates. In my question, the code needs to display the first list item on 2020-02-15, then continue from there.

Comment: @MikeHermary I've edited my answer and now it should work as intended.